# Unable to set size of components correclty

Tags: java, swing

I made a simple swing program to display Text Area and a button below it, but even after using setBounds(), button is getting displayed over full Frame. Here is my code-

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Exp2
{
  public static void main(String... s)
  {
    JFrame jf=new JFrame("Exec");
    JTextArea jtv=new JTextArea("Hello World");
    jtv.setBounds(5,5,100,60);
    JButton jb=new JButton("click");
    jb.setBounds(40,160,100,60);
    jf.add(jtv);
    jf.add(jb);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(500,500);
    jf.setResizable(false);
    jf.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

[After Execution of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6TlJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

The default layout manager for a frame is a `BorderLayout`. So you can't just add the button directly to the frame.

Instead your logic should be something like:

```
JButton button = new JButton(...);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add(button);
frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

The default layout for a `JPanel` is a `FlowLayout` which will display the button at its preferred size.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information about the `BorderLayout` and `FlowLayout`.